# Javascript Simple Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm playing around in the console, trying to understand prototypal inheritance. I'm familiar with classical inheritance, but I've never used any inheritance in my JS work.

If I have:

```
var foo = {
    cat: "oliver"
}

var bar = Object.create(foo);

foo.prototype = {
    dog: "rover"
}
```

When I do:

```
dir(bar.dog)
```

or

```
dir(foo.dog)
```

I expect to see `rover` but they both come back as `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess where I am confused is this: the prototype property on works on instantiated objects (functions) and yet Object.create is able to use an object literal as a prototype? Or does that pattern only work with constructors?

Comment: You cannot set prototype on object instances (like the foo object literal) and expect it to work like setting prototype on Functions. All you did was add a property named prototype on foo but JS runtime won't use it to look up. David has given the most correct answer. More info on what  prototype is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be the correct code to accomplish what you are trying:

```
var foo = Object.create({dog:'rover'});

foo.cat = 'oliver';

var bar = Object.create(foo);
```

this way `foo` inherits from an object with a property called `dog`, then `bar` inherits from that same object because it inherits from `foo`

Now, check with `bar.dog` and `bar.cat` it prints `rover` and `oliver` respectively

notice that `.prototype` only works to access or set the prototype object of functions, what you're doing in that code is wrong, this is correct:

```
var a = function(){
}

a.prototype = {};
```

to access the prototype of an object you do it like this:

```
a = {};

a.\__proto__.foo = 'bar';
```

however this allows you to get or set properties of that prototype object but not replace it for a different one.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing this because of this line:

```
foo.prototype = {
    dog: "rover"
}
```

You can't change an object's prototype after you create that object.

What you can do is modify the existing prototype like this:

```
foo.dog = "rover";
```

Remember that `foo` is the prototype of `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype members are only available when you instantiate it. `foo.cat` is available because it's like "a static" property (from languages that have this kind of code support, like PHP for example). Also, you should inherit from the `foo` prototype when doing your `Object.create`

```js
var foo = function(){ };
foo.cat = "oliver";

var bar = Object.create(foo.prototype);

foo.prototype.dog = "rover";

console.log(bar.dog); // yields "rover", modifying the prototype of "foo" alter the members of "bar" instance
```